# Spring Batch Paging with sortKeys and parameter values

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-batch, spring-boot

I have a Spring Batch project running in Spring Boot that is working perfectly fine. For my reader I'm using JdbcPagingItemReader with a MySqlPagingQueryProvider.

```
@Bean
public ItemReader<Person> reader(DataSource dataSource) {
    MySqlPagingQueryProvider provider = new MySqlPagingQueryProvider()
    provider.setSelectClause(ScoringConstants.SCORING_SELECT_STATEMENT)
    provider.setFromClause(ScoringConstants.SCORING_FROM_CLAUSE)
    provider.setSortKeys("p.id": Order.ASCENDING)

    JdbcPagingItemReader<Person> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<Person>()
    reader.setRowMapper(new PersonRowMapper())
    reader.setDataSource(dataSource)
    reader.setQueryProvider(provider)
    //Setting these caused the exception
    reader.setParameterValues(
        startDate: new Date() - 31,
        endDate: new Date()
    ) 
    reader.afterPropertiesSet()
    return reader
}
```

However, when I modified my query with some named parameters to replace previously hard coded date values and set these parameter values on the reader as shown above, I get the following exception on the **second** page read (the first page works fine because the _id parameter hasn't been made use of by the paging query provider):

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No value supplied for the SQL parameter '_id': No value registered for key '_id'
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray(NamedParameterUtils.java:336)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.getPreparedStatementCreator(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:374)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:192)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:199)
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader.doReadPage(JdbcPagingItemReader.java:218)
at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractPagingItemReader.doRead(AbstractPagingItemReader.java:108)
```

Here is an example of the SQL, which has no WHERE clause by default. One does get created automatically when the second page is read:

```
select *, (select id from family f where date_created between :startDate and :endDate and f.creator_id = p.id)  from person p
```

On the second page, the sql is modified to the following, however it seems that the named parameter for _id didn't get supplied:

```
select *, (select id from family f where date_created between :startDate and :endDate and f.creator_id = p.id) from person p WHERE id > :_id
```

I'm wondering if I simply can't use the MySqlPagingQueryProvider sort keys together with additional named parameters set in JdbcPagingItemReader. If not, what is the best alternative to solving this problem? I need to be able to supply parameters to the query and also page it (vs. using the cursor). Thank you!

Comment: You don't seem to be setting the where clause for your new values.  Is that just missing from your configuration example?

Comment: @MichaelMinella Thank you for your help. I provided some SQL above. There is no WHERE clause in my initial query, however the paging provider automatically adds one after the first page.

Comment: I meant that when you configure your provider, you aren't setting the where clause for the startDate and endDate, or am I missing something?

Comment: @MichaelMinella, note that those are not used in the where clause, but rather in a subselect. Do you think for some reason that that would cause the issue I am having with the _id field? I realize I could change that to a join instead of a subselect and use a where clause, but I have many additional sub selects that can't be made into joins that I've removed for the sake of trying to reduce confusion. The query is tested and works. Like I said, page 1 functions fine and it isn't until page 2 where the WHERE clause automatically gets added, that the named _id param isn't bound. Thank you again!

Comment: Looking at the [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcPagingItemReader.java) and how the getParameterMap function works it certainly seems to cover it.  Any chance you can turn on the logging and see what is output for "Using parameterMap"?

Comment: th3morg, can you put together a simple test case and throw it up on git?

Comment: Thank you guys for trying to help! I think this issue was a bit obscure and difficult to diagnose without having all of the parts, which I apologize for. I appreciate the time taken. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem with some intense debugging. It turns out that MySqlPagingQueryProvider utilizes a method `getSortKeysWithoutAliases()` when it builds up the SQL query to run for the first page and for subsequent pages. It therefore appends `and (p.id > :_id)` instead of `and (p.id > :_p.id)`. Later on, when the second page sort values are created and stored in JdbcPagingItemReader's `startAfterValues` field it will use the original `"p.id"` String specified and eventually put into the named parameter map the pair `("_p.id",10)`. However, when the reader tries to fill in _id in the query, it doesn't exist because the reader used the non-alias removed key.

Long story short, I had to remove the alias reference when defining my sort keys.

`provider.setSortKeys("p.id": Order.ASCENDING)`

had to change to in order for everything to work nicely together

`provider.setSortKeys("id": Order.ASCENDING)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and got another possible solution.

My table T has a primary key field INTERNAL_ID.

The query in JdbcPagingItemReader was like this:

```
SELECT INTERNAL_ID, ... FROM T WHERE ... ORDER BY INTERNAL_ID ASC
```

So, the key is: in some conditions, the query **didn't return results**, and then, raised the error above *No value supplied for...*

The solution is:

- Check in a Spring Batch **decider** element if there are rows.
- If it is, continue with chunk: reader-processor-writer.
- It it's not, go to another step.

Please, note that they are two different scenarios:

- At the beginning, there are rows. You get them by paging and finally, there are no more rows. This has no problem and decider trick is not required.
- At the beginning, there are no rows. Then, this error raised, and the decider solved it.

Hope this helps.